# postgres spatial indexing

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, geolocation, geospatial

I can't seem to find much documentation on this.
What's the simplest way to create a database/table on postgres supporting a query like this  SELECT * FROM table WHERE distance(POINT(0,0), table.location) <= 1000m;
Where POINT(0,0) and table.location should be latitude/longitude pair, and 1000m is 1000 meters. And how should I go about indexing that table?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PostgreSQL support indexes on expressions and also partial indexes, you can probably mix them.

This is just a random guess, I don't know if it works, but give it a try:

```
CREATE INDEX foobar ON table (distance(POINT(0,0), location))
 WHERE distance(POINT(0,0), location) <= 1000;
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/indexes-expressional.html

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/indexes-partial.html

Comment: Bear in mind that Earth is not flat.  Such planimetric calculations won't work well in general case.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked into Postgis and contrib/earthdistance?

http://www.postgis.org/

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/earthdistance.html