# How to compare the current location against a list of addresses and come up with nearby addresses within 5 miles/10 miles/20 miles?

Tags: java, android, geolocation, geocoding

How do mobile apps like yelp and gasbuddy find a list of nearby restaurants/gas stations? I am creating an Android app and have a list of locations in my database. I want to give the user all the nearby locations from my database based on the user's current location. What is the best way to go about it? I am using Java.

Comment: Geo-code all your addresses and store lat/lon for each one.  Then, based on the location, compute the distances between current lat/lon and the pairs for each address.

Answer (score 0):

Some databases actually have this built in; for example [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944880/postgres-spatial-indexing) a StackOverflow question about spatial queries in Postgres, which should set you on the right path. Your app would send coordinates to a server, which would use those coordinates to query a postgres database directly.

Answer (score 0):

This link may be helpful http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/92885-distance-between-2-points/
when you get the distance just compre it with if or whatever you want and then show it or save.