# latitude and longitude of the location using any opensource

Tags: javascript, perl, api

How to retrieve the location latitude and longitude.

*Input*: user enter the  location name.

*Output*:latitude and longitude of the location entered by the user.

Point to be noted:

> ***it must be free (not like google.) and also support  more than 20
>   millions requests per day. Solution may be of any type 
>   online(api,javascript) or offline(text,.csv files)***

Already gone through the Mapquest,openstreet Map services but in the case of Mapquest they need money and in case of openstreet limit is on the number of queries

I m looking for a solution like use the tiles of the map from mapquest, use the leaflet javascript or openlayer javascript to send query to the mapquest server which is free  as per my search  but the problem is that to request the map we need to give them latitude and longitude of the location (geo-code of the location) on the basis of which they provide the tiles maintaining the database for this is not good step because on the basis of location there are lots of places with the same name in all over the world .. but we need the geo code of the location same or approximately 90% correct in comparison  of the google.

---

Comment: Any efforts from your side?

Comment: Someone has erroneously up voted this when there is clearly no apparent effort. Please at least attempt it, and show [what you have tried](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDUQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmattgemmell.com%2F2008%2F12%2F08%2Fwhat-have-you-tried&ei=LSM3UYr0E-_yyAGyj4DYBw&usg=AFQjCNEaDvK0Yfyka3MM4mxwm1_e8khNEw&sig2=U8E_eQeG-3I90Adh3YotCQ&bvm=bv.43287494,d.aWc). Give you your -1 back when you do.

Comment: a google query for `free geocoding api` should get you started. **I am doubtful you will find one with no limits**

Comment: -1: No effort from your side

Comment: Javascript, C++ or Perl? Very odd requirements...

Comment: http://leafletjs.com/ javascript for javascript

Comment: What does that link tell us? What you'd like to emulate or what you've produced?

Comment: An Open-Source JavaScript Library for Interactive Maps which uses the longitude and the latitude of the location

Comment: I am new to SO. I have edited the Question. Please remove the downvotes on my Question.

Comment: 20 million requests per day is quite a lot of bandwidth for the server, I doubt anybody will give you that for free.

Comment: ready to pay but not that much as demanded by google

Answer (score 5):

### Openstreetmap

Or you can use openstreetmap data. [They have a worldwide database with it, all 23G of it](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm#Worldwide_data).

You can download all of that and use it as you wish.

You can use [Geo::Parse::OSM](https://metacpan.org/module/Geo::Parse::OSM) to parse the 23 gigabytes OSM file you get from openstreetmap.

### Ad-hoc solution

If you want to geocode by location lat/long I suggest you make a [table in Postgresql and do some spatial indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944880/postgres-spatial-indexing). You can put in that table everything Maxmind has in their db(see below) or you can put the data from Openstreetmap(see below). Then you can do quick searches on that table.
Postgresql probably has a [quadtree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) data structure or something similar in it that allows it to easily search through the entries in that table.

[Here is another presentation that tells you how you can spatially index your data](http://postgis.refractions.net/files/OSDB2_PostGIS_Presentation.pdf) in the table and what kind of queries you can do on it.
Here's an example:

```
create table pubs (name varchar,beer_price float4);
addgeometrycolumn(‘beer_db’,'pubs','location’,2167,'POINT',3);
insert into pubs values ( 'Garricks Head', 4.50, 
     GeometryFromText( 'POINT (1196131 383324)’   ,2167));

select name, beer_price, 
distance(location, GeometryFromText('POINT(1195722 
383854)',2167)) 
from pubs order by beer_price;

  name           | beer_price |     distance     
  ---------------+------------+------------------
  Fireside       |       4.25 | 1484.10275160491
  The Forge      |       4.33 | 1533.06561109862
```

You might bump into another problem which is, what exactly do you mean by lat/long because a city might be a point, a circle, or a polygon depending on how you define it.
Maybe you want points in a certain radius from the lat/long of a city.

### Maxmind

I guess it depends what you mean by location. If you're talking city, country, state, zipcode, areacode, things like that then use [Maxmind web service](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/web-services#Perl-5).In that link you find information about querying Maxmind. But you need a license key which you can buy from them.

They also have a [C API for querying that service](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/downloadable#C_API-3).

Alternatively, for offline use you can [get their free offline Maxmind db](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geolite).

### Google Maps

If you want to geolocate at the street level, [I suggest you use Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial).
If you want to do so many requests you will need an API key which you'll have to pay for.

They have a business package which also and [you can see the detailed comparison here](http://www.google.com/enterprise/earthmaps/maps-compare.html). They allow you to find 100,000 addresses per day.

Comment: i m switching from google because they are now demanding money for large number of queries

Comment: @user1517413 They let you try for free and then demand money when you've become successful; terrible!

Answer (score 1):

Open Street Map. A free world map. **The data is free to download**(unlike google) and use under its open license.

[***This***](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) will rock your world :)

Comment: @MayurkhRoy The user has already told that he has tried using openstreet, but they have limit of usage.

Comment: And for unlimited usage, we need to set up our own servers hosting these maps. This is way too costly!

Comment: Oh..I missed that, but again, the data is free to download an using Spatial Queries, most of the times basic needs are fulfilled at ease.
The restriction is on their server usage only I guess, not if we download and use their data..